# Using importHTML works 9 out of 10 times. Thinking of including a feedback loop, but how?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using the importHTML function to pull the current prices of the top 100 crypto coins from Coingecko to a Google Sheet. It works great most of the times, but sometimes the formula goes to N/A in these two cases:

- After having the sheet open for a few hours of inactivity;
- After reloading the formula to get updated prices.

This is the code I'm using in my Macro, which is triggered once a day in the morning to get the updated prices:

*spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=importhtml("https://www.coingecko.com/";"table";1)')*

As mentioned, it works great 9 out of 10 times. But how do I get it right 10 out of 10 times? I'm no programmer, but I would love to have a loop where the script checks the following:

"If the cell A1 returns N/A, wait 30 seconds and refresh formula. Keep repeating this action until the cell is not N/A anymore". Or give up after 10 tries (to avoid an infinite loop).

Not sure if this logic is correct or if there is even a better logic out there, but happy to hear your advice!

Many thanks in advance,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate(); 
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=ifna(importhtml("https://www.coingecko.com/";"table";1);importhtml("https://www.coingecko.com/";"table";1))')
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try and put a trigger on that function

```
function importTable() {
  var url = 'https://www.coingecko.com/'
  var n = 1
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { followRedirects: true, muteHttpExceptions: true }).getContentText().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|  )/gm, "")
  const tables = [...html.matchAll(/<table[\s\S\w]+?<\/table>/g)];
  var trs = [...tables[n - 1][0].matchAll(/<tr[\s\S\w]+?<\/tr>/g)];
  var data = [];
  trs.forEach(tr => {
    var tds = [...tr[0].matchAll(/<(td|th)[\s\S\w]+?<\/(td|th)>/g)];
    var prov = [];
    tds.forEach(td => {
      donnee = td[0].match(/(?<=\>).*(?=\<\/)/g)[0];
      prov.push(donnee.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g, ""));
    })
    data.push(prov);
  })
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  sh.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data)
}
```

[url-fetch-app#advanced-parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#advanced-parameters)

[matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)

### other solution with custom function

B1 is a checkbox to refresh if needed

```
=importTableHTML(url,1,B1)
```

with

```
function importTableHTML(url, n) {
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { followRedirects: true, muteHttpExceptions: true }).getContentText().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|  )/gm, "")
  const tables = [...html.matchAll(/<table[\s\S\w]+?<\/table>/g)];
  var trs = [...tables[n - 1][0].matchAll(/<tr[\s\S\w]+?<\/tr>/g)];
  var data = [];
  trs.forEach(tr => {
    var tds = [...tr[0].matchAll(/<(td|th)[\s\S\w]+?<\/(td|th)>/g)];
    var prov = [];
    tds.forEach(td => {
      donnee = td[0].match(/(?<=\>).*(?=\<\/)/g)[0];
      prov.push(donnee.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g, ""));
    })
    data.push(prov);
  })
  return (data)
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, many thanks for your answer, I really appreciate it. Could you perhaps explain what it is this script does?

Also when running it I get the following message: "This project requires your permission to access your data."

Why does this code need my permission and other codes don't?

Comment: Because it's not a custom function, but a script that will be launched by a trigger. This script will fetch the data inside the source page with some parameters `{ followRedirects: true, muteHttpExceptions: true }` which will prevent failures. I edited my question with references.

Comment: Hi Mike, in both cases (your code above and the link you provided) I have to link my Google account. Here I'm getting a safety warning to be careful with using unverified apps from a 3rd party. As I'm no developer and don't understand the risks, I will not use the code. Thank you for your time though, I'm sure that for developers this makes sense!

In case you have a simpler solution that does not require using external apps / permission, I'd of course be happy to see it

Comment: as you wish, there is no risk, you can see the code! I will add a solution with a custom function and test it if it doesn't require permission.

Comment: take a copy https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QgL3Abzr9w9P2iJiUyM4y9PWUIZ2w6sC3yLfFgrqO00/copy it doesn't require permission, click on B1 to refresh

Comment: The copied file looks great! However, when I copy and paste the code from the copied file to my own Google Sheet it still asks for permission. Any way around that?

Comment: It requires permission because you have another script in it? I don't have a solution, but you can be confident it's a common procedure, and the code is completely open and short.